# Possible Factors that secure a Tyrants power

Tags: magic, politics, organizations

**The Problem**

Picture this: an **incompetent** and **uncharacteristic** hereditary monarch to whom I will now refer to as the **“Last Monarch”**.

The problem with him is that he is rather **unsuited for retaining power**. Meaning that there would be little he could do to if someone wanted his position.

Therefore I shifted to finding potential **structures** that would make trying to topple someone like him a bad idea. And this is **where I need help**.

**Possible Solutions**

I have narrowed it down to **3 Factors** I need help with:

***Magical Factor:*** Any magical **ability** or **artifact** that make removing him from power a lot harder. Though to note here that would prefer something **not directly combat related**.

***Structural Factor:*** Possible ideas for **Organizations** that would help keep the "Last Monarch" in power.

***Motivational Factors:*** Any **advantages** that could possibly be gained by keeping someone like the “Last Monarch" in power.

**Additional Factors**

- The magic of the “Last Monarchs” country mainly focuses on **Necromancy** and **Dark Magic**.
- Possible Solutions **should not** be able to be **compromised** by unrest.
- The last Monarch **can't use magic** without an artifact

***Special Note:***

This question can longer be improved as doing so invalidate existing answers. Furthermore the problems of this question are to broad to effectively fix them. Due to this i marked the best answer on this question. I thank you all for your answers and participation.

**This answer will no longer receive edits from me personally. But if you are feeling you may be able to improve this question in any way you are free to do so.**

Comment: What is the question?  If the question is "write my story of how this war plays out" then that is off topic for this site - we help build worlds, not plots.

Comment: The question is how he can realistically stay in power in such in his current situation sorry if did not clarify this

Comment: Ever heard of Mao, Stalin, Hitler, Pol Pot? Anyone? ANYONE?!

Comment: Any question that is about the decisions of a particular person or group of people is off topic, sorry.  Sometimes a question can be tweaked into how a particular system can be made to function, but this is not a dynamic scenario that is the basis of your story.  (Also, 25% of the population dead means that the economy is not bad, it has collapsed already.  Looking at WW2 for comparison, no country lost that much of its population, even Germany *only* lost about 11% by the end of the war.)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to make the question clear, Fallenspacerock? (@Alastor Sorry, who?)

Comment: **KerrAvon2055** and **Joachim** i am sorry if my question is not clear enough or of topic. I will change it as soon as i have time for it. If you have any specific suggestions to improve my question just let me know.

Comment: you already answered your own questions with the things in his favor, I suggest you look at the history of real dictators because you described their situation quite well.

Comment: **John** I genuinely his situation is worse as he laks a cult of personality. His country is also currently experiencing apocalyptic events and some of his inner circle want him dead. He is also very bad at getting rid of his political opponents. So i do think he needs some more things in his favor to survive politically which in his position is surviving at all.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock There is a difference between a dictator _creating_ a cult of personality and people actually _being part of this cult_. It isn't because the dictator tries very hard to create the "love me love me" image that people actually like him.

Comment: You pretty much described North Korea here

Comment: Not exactly the regime of North Korea has a lot of propaganda and a giant cult of personality among other things. Generally my monarch has no Cult of personality at least not one focused entirely on him. His mages have more of an status of being feared though something of this might reflect back on him.

Comment: *His country's economy is in a worse state than USA in the "Great Depression"* - This is still marvelous and great by standards for late antiquitity, middle ages or even post-WW1 Germany.

Comment: I think this question can't be saved anymore (you can, of course, create a new question; maybe through the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)?): this q is asking to mind-storm ideas, which is not a good fit. On the other hand, former edits have already disqualified some of the existing answers, which is also no good. And your edits have mostly focused on rewording the structure and narrative, but not the question at its foundation, which is where the problem lies :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment **joachim**. You may be right that it might be a good idea to abandon the question entirely. Though there are still a few things i want to try before i decide to just let it rest. Any idea how i could correctly restructure question?Or how i could correctly ask for ideas to secure a rulers power on this platform. Anyways i am glad you took your time to comment. I thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tyrants don't need majority support

Tyrants are typically hated by most of thier people.  The point of tyranny is not to earn popular favor, but to earn so much favor with a specific group that are willing to turn militant against the majority.  Imagine a world in which mages were persecuted just a few generations before.  They had all this power, but are too few and far between to stand up to a mob of fearful villagers; so, along comes the "last King's" ancestor with ambitions for the crown.  Instead of starting off with a reign of terror, he starts off by giving a disenfranchised minority rights that no other lord is willing to give.  He passes laws that allow mages to openly practice magic.  He turns the graveyards into public domain for the necromancers.  He allocates large parts of his fiefdom to the training and education of mages, etc.  So, mages from all over flock to his fiefdom, even though he is not a mage himself.

Once he's elevated thier status, this ancestor starts preaching about how the fearful majority have mistreated mages for so long, and how mages need to stand up for the right to be safe in thier own lands. So, he stokes the flames of hate and resentment that are already there, and he leads a rebellion of mages.  Even though these mages are few in number, they are much more powerful than they have ever been because the first tyrant united them. This creates a deep and true loyalty for the new king and his dynasty, but the new social order basically turns every other non-magic user into slaves.  With a powerful and united 1% at his command, he can rule the reluctant and disorganized 99%.

### Forced Masks of Loyalty

Because of this history, the Royal family rules and the magocracy follows them out of loyalty, but in time the quality of leadership degrades and and the loyalty of the magocracy starts to fade... but like I said, Tyrants don't need majority support.  Many tyrants grow to be hated, even by thier inner circle.  The trick is to force your inner circle to all put on a mask of loyalty, and make sure that they are never allowed to drop that mask long enough to organize an uprising.

Imagine you are a powerful mage in a room with 10 other powerful mages, and if you don't agree with everything the tyrant says, you know for a fact that he will command the other 10 mages to kill you.  They will obey, not because they respect or fear the tyrant, but because they fear that the other mages will obey, and they believe the other 10 mages will obey.  Moreover, because convincing public declarations of loyalty are a required part of daily life for these mages, the other 10 mages all appear like they could be very loyal, making even talking about a coup a REALLY dangerous bluff to call.

These 10 archmages might each rule over thier own council of lesser mages who they are required by law to enforce the same reign of terror over.  And those lesser mages do the same to those under them.  In this way, there is a cascading rule of fear over the magocracy in which the mages are all forced to fear each other, and this fear makes them obedient... no matter how much they privately hate those who are over them.  In this way, the king, despite being hated and incompetent in every other way maintains an iron fist of control over all the nation's real power. And with the public perceiving the mages as being absolutely loyal to the king, they would fear the mages the way the common people of Germany feared the Gestapo or the Soviets feared the KGB.

The second part of this equation is making sure that the mask is never allowed to drop.  King Louis XIII really set the example for this sort of tyranny.  Each of his nobles were provided a personal servant that they did not get to pick on thier own.  While called servants, these people were more what we now call government handlers: people appointed to make sure that important people of interest don't step out of line.  If a lord tried meeting in secret, sneaking away without his servant, or if something suspicious ever happend to an appointed servant, then the suspicion of disloyalty was immediate and dangerous for said lord. So, this can help prevent even private conversations of disloyalty from happening because you are always being watched.

Unlike a king who leads through charisma, he does not actually need the support of people who follow him out of loyalty because there will always be enough people following him out of fear to keep the system going. And, because the Last King acquired his position through heredity, he does not need to be clever enough to enact this campaign of fear mongering on his own.  He was born into this life.  Killing a mage for not smiling during the pledge of allegiance is just the way of things, handed down to him from his father. He might even have rules prominently engraved on the wall  of his throne room by his father to remind him of when to order someone killed... in case he forgets.   A simpleton just following the rules is in many ways even harder to dethrone than a wiser man because he can not be tempted to bend the rule enough to make himself vulnerable.  Wise kings know when to show mercy if it means averting a war, famine, or trade embargo, but a foolish king will make no exceptions.  This makes his kingdom very vulnerable to outside threats, but rock solid against rebellion.

### If you feel he needs a real ally to keep him in his seat...

Under many feudal systems, if his father dies before the first born came of age, a distant family member or trusted noble would be appointed regent to rule and raise the prince until he comes of age.  In your setting where the family is dispersed, this would likely have been the patriarch of the most powerful clan of mages.  Since it was not uncommon for a regent to retain a Vizier like status after the king ascended to the throne, he would need the royal line to stay intact in order to retain his elevated status over the other archmages.

As such, there will always be at least one very power mage (both magically and politically) who would have a real vested interest in protecting the bad king.

Comment: Generally a good answer the ancestors of the "last monarch" definitively could have created such a system. The only problem is that the monarch now is rather incompetent and he alone cannot really generate fear neither towards his inner circle nor to the population. He would need the support of a few powerful mages to do such a thing.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock See added last paragraph

Comment: Definitely going to consider it but he might need some to personally keep him in check as well.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock You could give him a Regent or Vizier.  See added section.

Comment: Yes definitely would help. Any reason why he would help the monarch. Like what benefits might he get out of this.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock There is no single set of rules that spans all cultures and time periods, but in many cases royal advisers were placed second in command, above all the other non-royal nobility, giving them the authority to pass laws and judgements "on the king's behalf".   The key here is that his authority is derived from the monarchy.  If If the king is overthrown, then he could no longer speak on the king's behalf making him just another archmage.  In fact, it's likely he would be executed along with the king for doing such a bad job of raising him.

Comment: Yes thank you that could possibly make him not want to lose his position by making a risky move and killing him. Or letting him get killed as both would harm his power.

Answer (score 4):

He has no talent but one, he can sense universes diverging, with his sixth sense choosing the one were he survives against all odds.
Like a many-world aware roulett player he walks away from unwinnable tables winning, because he turns the right way, waits the right seconds. Shivering, drooling, fooling he yet tumbles ever onwards and as the world around gets ever odder, ever bizarrer, even his opponents are aware of this ability, this predicament, to move into ever stranger worlds, the more they pile on him.

Comment: While he does not have this power personally. I think it could be logical for one of his subordinates to have it or maybe he could have an artifact for that. Overall thank you for your suggestion deviation is definitely an option i will consider.

Comment: Maybe it was his ceremonial duties to undertake the title of the king but ruling of the country still falls into the president and the cabinet.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to give you some tips on the state of the world in which your points may make sense.

**The war is slow and positional, but has the highest stakes.**

Everyone feels the impact of the war; trade has died, every family has lost someone to it, some villages have lost all their male population in a matter of weeks, fields lay unattended, and food is scarce. However, for most, the frontline is distant enough that they don't have to fear unexpected raids or stray fireballs hitting their houses. No one is happy; everybody starves and mourns, but at the same time, they mostly don't feel the war directly. Also, everybody knows that if the lines break, they will be dragged to Hell or infected by brain-eating fungus, or face whatever grim fate the two antagonistic kingdoms have up their sleeves.

**He is the least of many evils.**

You almost said it - the people who run the country, who keep the king as a puppet and scapegoat, are all evil necromancers who greatly benefit from the free corpses generated by the war. Therefore, they have no incentive to stop the war even if the ruler were dethroned. They openly desire all normal non-magic populace to become cheap undead labor. Our incompetent ruler (non-user himself) sometimes manages to unwittingly stumble upon some kind of ruling that actually protects the normal people. Not enough to actually better their position, but sufficient to keep them thankful enough to crack jokes instead of starting to rebel.

**Alternatively - They are stuck with him because of higher power.**

The ruler is a non-magic user, but he is magical himself. Anyone who openly rebels, disobeys, plots to hurt, or dethrone him gets cursed together with their extended family and up to five generations with the "most crippling fate worse than death." Jokes are the upper safe limit. Spitting on his image gets you cursed, conspiring against him gets all conspirators cursed, writing that you want to kill him in your diary gets you cursed. If he attempted to abdicate by his own free will, it would get him cursed together with all his children, and everyone cheering for that will get cursed as well.

Intrigue is still possible, but the conspirators need to be mindful that their actions won't hurt the ruler directly; otherwise, all of them and everybody on the attached strings will get cursed.

Comment: Neat ideas the first two are in someway already in my setting. But i especially like the last idea though I would make the curse less expensive. As the country who he is waging war against very clearly want him dead and plan as well as talk about it openly. And i don't to just kill them all.

Answer (score 3):

He can coast for quite a while on **infighting between foreign factions within the government**. For a real-life example, look at the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth in the 18th century: a notionally big country with great potential, if only it were not constantly torn apart by Saxon, Prussian, Russian, French, Swedish, etc. factions. It ticks most of your required boxes, except the supernatural ones:

- At Least 25% of his country's population is dead

Much of the Great Northern War of 1700-1721 took place on PLC's territory, which was devastated as a result, causing the popluation to drop (by about 10%; but then this came on top of the losses during the equally tumultous late 17th century, and all these put together do amount to 25% of pre-conflict population).

- Yes they are starving

...due to the conflicts listed above. That explains much of the dying.

- A good proportion of his population dislikes him to the point they openly make jokes at his expense

At the height of the Great Northern War, PLC had not one but *two* kings (one Saxony-sponsored and the other Sweden-sponsored), *both* of which jointly appear in a proverbial description of disorder, which is occasionally used to this day.

- His country's economy is in a worse state than USA in the "Great Depression"

Yep; it was like USA fighting its Civil War *during* the Great Depression.

- He is currently wagging an unsustainable war with this economy he is unwilling to end

See above; being foreign-sponsored, the king could hardly make his own peace.

- An not negligible part of his inner circle want him dead

Not dead perhaps, but the PLC's nobility rebelled throughout the 18th century with monotonous regularity.

- He also has an atrocious charisma and horrible political skills

Not really; at the very least, they had to be savy enough to get themselves elected. (And Augustus II the Strong was an absolute [*chad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus_II_the_Strong#Illegitimate_issue).)

- He is easy to manipulate and so a good puppet

As all of them were, due to being propped by one or the other of the foreign powers.

- A lot of powerful people profit of his incompetence due to a lack of control

See above; it's just that most of these people live abroad... ;)

- Despite every thing he is a stabilizing factor for his regime and him dying might have horrible consequences

Very much so; should the king die, the foreign powers might well drag the country into a succession war and devastate it in the process (*again*...).

- There is no other member of the royal family left as his children fled long ago

PLC was an elective monarchy; the king's children had no claim on the throne anyway.

- His population and Elite knows that if they lose the war their country's going to get annexed

As indeed [it eventually was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Lithuanian_Commonwealth#Partitions_(1772%E2%80%931795)). But to be honest, the political class did not fear it, as much as lived in denial until the thing actually happened.

Comment: A lot of great ideas and yes the country is on a inevitable downward spiral though they are fine from now on. The king him self is not foreign sponsored and a hereditary monarch which is important for my world. But the infighting is definitely happening.

Comment: In times of rebellion, even heiratary monarchs can easily become "foreign sponsored".

Answer (score 2):

## He persuades the mages to make him the controller of the undead

The undead are programmed and commanded by mages. He has convinced the mages that major programming changes need royal approval, because of the risk of hostile necromancers seizing control of the undead, and so the undead are fanatically loyal to him personally.

The major power players and nobles are fine with this because while they hate him, they hate their rivals more and he's the least controversial choice.

If he died then with no one to replace him, the undead would quickly get out of control. While in the short run standing orders would make it fine, it would risk an undead plague sweeping through the land, especially given the military and economic weaknesses which would make reprogramming them hard.

The king needs to live, or everyone dies.

Comment: While i do think he would make a political puppet that necromancers use for political benefit. I find it unlikely that the would give him control of their undead to such extent that they are completely defenseless.

Comment: They would have standing orders, e.g. obey a particular necromancer and fight their enemies, but to be reprogrammed they would need a royal order. E.g. bob the necromancer commands the 51st legion, they have a royal decree and can do whatever. They get killed by a sniper, and the undead will stand and fight, but won't obey any others orders till they get a new royal order to fight.

This has the advantage that killing your superior necromancer officer means you might die- you can't seize an army without royal approval.

Comment: Death by sniper is definitely not an uncommon fate for a necromancer. And discouraging others from killing you by by depriving them of certain benefits could work especially with how easy the monarch can be manipulated. I am also going to write that down for when i eventually come around to building the undead army and its command structure. So thank you for your input.

Comment: I would imagine before the royal commands on undead, it could be common for underlings to kill their superior, claim death by sniper, and send their superior's corpse and their army to win glory for them. An easily manipulated king lets you better entrench power among the right necromancers.

Comment: Yes exactly it could maybe have been a development. Like after a lot a necromancers died in such a manner.

Comment: Yeah. And it fits in with the overall theme- his army is corrupt and violent and he is truly the last monarch. Even if he died, they would need to necromancer him because they can't afford to not have him exist.

Comment: The funny thing is that is exactly what what happens to him later down the road. Well at least sort of what happens as it is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The story is told of one cruel ruler when asked by foreign delegates how he kept in power, he took them out into a grain field and knocked off the heads of any stalk that stood above the rest.

A tyrant can stay in power as long as he kills off any possible replacement.

That may include people who could return to the country and lead a revolution. Thus, Russia has often killed exiles who could lead any resistance. (Lenin was not killed while in exile. Stalin learned that lesson and had Trotsky killed.)

Comment: While generally a good advice the monarch of my world neither has the possibility nor the skills to do so. At least not with out some help.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock Of course. Putin has the secret police to help him. Have you noticed all the Russian Oligarchs falling out of windows to their deaths?

Comment: Yeah it would definitely make sense for him to have a people helping him. But they would be a lot more autonomous and or often commanded by different people. This because the **"last monarch"** is rather incompetent